# Logging on to Facebook using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I want to log on to facebook using PHP, I use the example from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/) , so this example should work, but when I load the page and click link login the page reloads and nothing happens, there is still link login. I don't have any PHP errors. I know that my code 'ends' in catch section - after clicking login link.

```
<?php

require('facebook.php');


 // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
 // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/


 $config = array(
'appId' => 'appId',
'secret' => 'secret',
'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
'cookie'=>true
);

 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}

 ?>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do u have any redirect url in the application setting ?

Comment: In general you need to provide the canvas page URL and canvas page and site URL in the settings. Then while generating the login URL u need to provide the redirect_uri. Looks like something is missing in your case also make sure having the correct appId and secret value.

Comment: appId and secret value are correct, I printed the "exception value" - $e (I don't know if it is correct in english) and I discovered that there is  - CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host. I read this post and now I suppose that this is my free hosting's fault.

Comment: Yes u need to install curl.

Comment: Now I'm sure what is the problem. I have curl installed on my hosting but the part of Facebook API is blocked, it's free hosting so I have to buy paid hosting or change my free hosting. Another question, does anybody know free hosting with full access to Facebook API? Thanks in advance.